# How to display an object in ag grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

the data doesn't display.
here's the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-pvtbsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

***list.component.ts***

```
setAgGrid() {
    this.data.map((data: any) => {
      const date = new Date(data.date);
      const year = ('' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
      const assetColIndex = data.assetCode + '_' + date.getMonth() + '_' + year;

      if (this.columns.indexOf(assetColIndex) === -1) {
        this.columns.push(assetColIndex);
      }
    });

    const dataByMonthYr = this.data.reduce((dataByMonthYear: any, datum: any) => {
      const date = new Date(datum.date);
      const year = ('' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
      const monthYear = this.monthNames[date.getMonth()].monthName + '\'' + year;
      const assetColIndex = datum.assetCode + '_' + date.getMonth() + '_' + year;

      let dataIndex = dataByMonthYear.findIndex((data: any) => data.code === datum.code);

      if (dataIndex === -1) {
        dataByMonthYear.push({ code: datum.code });
        dataIndex = dataByMonthYear.length - 1;
      }

      let count = 0;

      this.columns.forEach((column: any) => {
        count = column === assetColIndex ? datum.assetCount : 0;

        dataByMonthYear[dataIndex][column] = (dataByMonthYear[dataIndex][column] || 0) + count;
      });

      const colHeaderIndex = this.columnDefs.findIndex((data: any) => data.headerName === monthYear);
      if (colHeaderIndex !== -1) {
        const colIndex = this.columnDefs[colHeaderIndex]
          .children.findIndex((data: any) => data.field === assetColIndex);
        if (colIndex === -1) {
          this.columnDefs[colHeaderIndex].children.push(
            {
              'headerName': datum.assetCode,
              'field': assetColIndex,
              'aggFunc': this.customAggFunction
            }
          );
        } else {
         this.columnDefs.push({
            headerName: monthYear,
            code: date.getMonth() + '_' + year,
            children: [
                // { headerName: "Style/Machine", field:   },
                {headerName: datum.assetCode, field: assetColIndex, width: 100, aggFunc: this.customAggFunction },
              ]
          });
        }
      }

      return dataByMonthYear;
    }, []);

    this.columnDefs.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.code < b.code) { return -1; }
      return 0;
    });


    console.log(this.columnDefs, dataByMonthYr);
    this.rowData.next(dataByMonthYr);
  }
```

How to display the objects in ag grid?

What I want to display is like this.
[image]

When I'm adding the `this.gridOptions.gridApi.setRowData(object)`
the gridApi doesn't recognized or the setRowData doesn't recognized.
EXPECTED out put.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste the code along with the question - this ensures that the question retains its validity if/when the external link dries out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the object in rowdata object 
 [rowData]="rowData"
in typescript 
file rowData= object

or use the setRowdata object 
 this.gridApi.setRowData(object);

And in order to display cell as you required,
use cellRenderer
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: I already try the this.gridApi.setRowData().
the setRowData doesn't recognize

Comment: have you declared gridApi of type GridApi?

Comment: yes and the error is cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

Comment: check your package.json file where the dependency of ag-grid present or not

Comment: where should I put the this.gridApi.setRowData()? inside the onGridReady or I can add it inside the setGrid?

Comment: inside onGridReady()

Comment: can you check if what's wrong. it doesn't display. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-pvtbsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sees to be a problem in the import of the module

Comment: What do you mean the module? you mean the ```modules = [ClientSideRowModelModule];```?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to why GridApi is undefined:**

Your `GridApi` is undefined because it is not getting initialized.

Add `gridReady` event to your template, like this:

```
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```

And in your component:

```
onGridReady(event){
 this.gridApi = event.api;
 this.setAgGrid();
}
```

**Answer to Why data is not getting display:**

[image]

As you can see in the image:
Your `columnDefs` and `rowData` are not in sync and irrelevant to what you want to display.

Your `columnDefs` has only one object whose `field` value is 'code'.

Add other fields as well that you want as your columns.

In 'rowData' keys name of object should match with `field` name of `columnDefs`.

You don't need to call `setAgGrid` twice, you can remove it from `ngOnInit`.

PS: If you change your `hide` from `false` to `true` in your `columnDefs`, you will start seeing your code column. And you don't need to use `BehaviorSubject`, just assign the array to your `rowData`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in the code, some syntax errors and some logical errors. I have tried fixing it with the basic understanding I got from reading the code.

Use `gridReady` event of ag-Grid to call the `setAgGrid()` method after the ag-Grid is initialized like below:

```
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```

And in your component file remove the OnInit method and declare a new function

```
onGridReady(event){
 this.gridApi = event.api;
 this.setAgGrid();
}
```

And also change these line inside `setAgGrid()` method like so (I added a new code of line and edited another line here).

```
this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs)
this.gridApi.setRowData(dataByMonthYr);
```

Replace the if condition in the code with the one given below, as the column definitions were not pushed to the `columnDefs` array because there was a mixup of the else condition in the two if cases.

```
if (colHeaderIndex !== -1) {
        const colIndex = this.columnDefs[colHeaderIndex]
          .children.findIndex((data: any) => data.field === assetColIndex);
        if (colIndex === -1) {
          this.columnDefs[colHeaderIndex].children.push(
            {
              'headerName': datum.assetCode,
              'field': assetColIndex,
              'aggFunc': this.customAggFunction
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        this.columnDefs.push({
          headerName: monthYear,
          code: date.getMonth() + '_' + year,
          children: [
            // { headerName: "Style/Machine", field:   },
            { headerName: datum.assetCode, field: assetColIndex, width: 100, aggFunc: this.customAggFunction },
          ]
        });
      }
```

I have got a similar output like the one you mentioned in the question. Also have created a stackblitz demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-wcss8k

Comment: How to show the style/machine? for example the january have only 2 machine which is the machine 1 have PRN with count 2 and machine 2 have PRN with count 1, then in february it has 3 machine then it has style/machine which is the machine 4, 5,6 and machine 4 have PRN with count 3 and machine 5 and 6 have PRN 2 with 5 count.
the machine 1 and 2 shouldn't display on the February

Comment: @ABC Change the `columnDefs` declared on top, set hide property to `false`

Comment: @ABC Please add a screenshot or sample of what result you are expecting.

Comment: it should display the month january to end of december

Comment: I already up the questionnaire, you can check the latest ouput